# Proper implementation of CanExecuteChanged

Tags: wpf, icommand

I have a View with multiple `Button`s and just as many `Command`s. For every `Command` I think I will have to implement `ICommand`. My program will contain a statemachine, so it will be possible that the CanExecute of the Commands will change run-time. 
The only implementation example of the `CanExecuteChanged` is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6426414/1770778):

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }     
}
```

But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6635754/1770778) it is stated that this implementation is a bad solution. `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` should be used.

But I cannot find a proper implementation of the `CanExecuteChanged` with `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048973/1770778) I find a basic example, but the user states it

> is a very simple implementation (which will probably throw a NullReferenceException occasionally)

I prefer code that doesn't throw exceptions once in a while. Does someone have a better example?

Answer (score 0):

You only need one implementation of the `ICommand` interface.

You could take a look at how the `RelayCommand` class is implemented in `MvvmLight` which is a popular but lightweight MVVM library: https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Command/RelayCommand.cs

It has a `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method that simply raises the `CanExecuteChanged` event. You should call this method whenever you want to "refresh" the command.

You could even download the `MvvmLight` assemblies and use the `RelayCommand` class directly in your application: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/